# Flexbox flex-wrap not allowing more than one item in dropdown - Bulma.css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

I am creating a webpage using the Bulma CSS files, and I have a problem with the navbar. So I am trying to customize the dropdown in the navbar a little bit, including having links side-by-side instead of up-down. This is what the default dropdown looks like in Bulma: [image: Image of bulma nav-dropdown]

However, I want to create something like this... **But with multiple rows**:

[image: Image of dropdown with side-by-side items]

And that's where my problem is. I can't make them go on to new lines after the max-width is reached, they just keep on going to the right side if I have a lot of items.

This is the HTML element structure:

```
                <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                    <a id="trending" class="navbar-link is-arrowless">Trending</a>
                    <div id="trending-dropdown" class="navbar-dropdown">
                      <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
                      <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
                      <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
                      <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
                      <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The `.navbar-dropdown` has `display: flex;` as well.

**Now, here's what I tried:**

1. adding a `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `.navbar-dropdown`: This just makes each element stay on its own line, just like what I already had in Bulma (see 1st img)
2. Giving a `flex: 1` to the `.navbar-item`s (I also used `flex-basis: 10%`)
3. Giving a max-width to the dropdown

This Is the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/coderDeveloper/pen/bGWpOva

```
   I really hope someone can help me as I'm at my wit's end 
               Thanks in advance!!
```

Comment: If you posted a Codepen link containing the entire navigation bar (instead of just the snippet of one menu item) it might be easier for someone to jump in and try to debug it for you.

Comment: @stevecomrie Ok I will

Comment: looks like you need to overide some bulma rules : possible example : https://jsfiddle.net/o7vjd9th/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a width of max-content on the parent with flex-wrap, maybe a gap, then on the children do a flex: *auto* or *0* depending on how you want the second line to layout, with min-width calculated to a percentage of the width of the parent.

***Parent element:***

```css
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: max-content;
```

***Child element:***

```css
  flex: 0;
  min-width: calc(33% - 1em);
```

[Link to your code pen with these settings](https://codepen.io/dlandry7/pen/NWjNeVz)

```css
.navbar-dropdown  {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: max-content;
  gap: 1em;
}

.navbar-dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-item:hover .navbar-dropdown {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-dropdown a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0;
  min-width: calc(33% - 1em);
  height: 2em;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
  <a id="trending" class="navbar-link is-arrowless">Trending</a>
  <div id="trending-dropdown" class="navbar-dropdown">
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
    <a class="navbar-item">Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lemme check it out :)